# Python logger is not creating log file despite a FileHandler being specified

Tags: python, logging

I've been using a logger to log messages to a file and also output them to the console. I don't believe I did anything wrong, but the log file hasn't been being created for a few of the runs that I did.

The code I have is:

```
log_msg_format = '[%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(filename)s: %(lineno)d] %(message)s'
handlers = [logging.FileHandler(filename=args.log_filename), logging.StreamHandler()]
logging.basicConfig(format=log_msg_format,
                    level=logging.INFO,
                    handlers=handlers)
```

When I check the logging level for each of the handlers, they are both `NOTSET`. I thought that this *might* be the problem, but the script is still outputting log messages to the console which means that this shouldn't be a problem.

What might be going wrong?

Comment: It works for me. Check for file permissions or something similar - if the file isn't being created at all, then that suggests that your code can't open the file to write to.

Comment: Make sure you don't have any handlers added to the root logger before the call to basicConfig. If any previously running code configures logging, basicConfig does nothing. There also is a `force` kwarg to override this behaviour.